# How to add/override method without extending class in php?

Tags: php, overriding

How to add/override method without extending class in php?

For an example:

```
<?php
DateTime.aMethod = function($inp)
{   //....
};

$datetime = new DateTime();

$datetime.aMethod('value');


DateTime.aStaticMethod = static function($inp)
{   //....
};

DateTime::aStaticMethod('value');
```

Comment: I think you are mistaking PHP for Ruby.

Comment: Or mistaking the falsy PHP object model with javascript prototyping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you cannot dynamically add methods to a class at runtime in PHP.

But you could try the runkit extension and try this experimental function: **[runkit_method_add](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php)**

> This function is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this function, its
>   name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a
>   future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.

Example:

```
<?php

runkit_method_add(
    'DateTime',
    'aMethod',
    '$inp',
    'return $inp;',
    RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC
);

$datetime = new DateTime();

$datetime->aMethod('value');

runkit_method_add(
    'DateTime',
    'aStaticMethod',
    '$inp',
    'return $inp;',
    RUNKIT_ACC_STATIC
);

DateTime::aStaticMethod('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

## Runkit is horrible

*Because, look at it ...*

The non-horrible answer to the question is `uopz`

- http://php.net/uopz

The non-horrible code is:

```
<?php
uopz_function(DateTime::class, "aMethod", function($arg){
    return $arg;
});

uopz_function(DateTime::class, "aStaticMethod", function($arg){
    return $arg;
}, ZEND_ACC_STATIC);
?>
```